# Update rows with max matches from rows of another table

Tags: postgresql, max, match, updates

I have `table1` around `8mln` lines and would like to update column `status` with maximum matches after searching from each rows in `tale2` (*maximum matches based on `rows from table2`*)

Example `table1`:

```
ID |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |  f  |  g  | grade | status |
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
01 | 100 | 101 | 105 | 108 | 110 | 126 | 188 |   x   |        |
```

Example `table2` (around `100k` lines):

```
 a  |  b  | c  |  d  | e  |  f  |  g  |
----------------------------------------
 75 | 101 |106 | 107 |110 | 122 | 188 |
100 | 104 |105 | 110 |114 | 126 | 188 |
 95 | 100 |105 | 108 |126 | 207 | 285 |
```

Based on the above examples, the outcome will be **5** because;

- from the 1st row `3` matches **[101, 110, 188]**
- from the 2nd row `5` matches **[100, 105, 110, 126, 188]**
- from the 3rd row `4` matches **[100, 105, 108, 126]**

so the maximum/highest match is **5** from the `second row` in `table2`

Example after updating `table1` column `status`:

```
ID |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |  f  |  g  | grade | status |
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
01 | 100 | 101 | 105 | 108 | 110 | 126 | 188 |   x   |   5    |
```

I am using the script shown here, but it's taking really long time to update the entire report and also the result is somehow not accurate.
So, I'd appreciate it if somebody could provide an alternative / better option/script by reducing the execution time of the query

```
UPDATE public.table1 AS t1 SET status = 
(SELECT MAX(tmp.mtch) FROM 
    (SELECT   (SELECT CASE WHEN t1.a=t2.a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
              (SELECT CASE WHEN t1.b=t2.b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
              (SELECT CASE WHEN t1.c=t2.c THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
              (SELECT CASE WHEN t1.d=t2.d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
              (SELECT CASE WHEN t1.e=t2.e THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
              (SELECT CASE WHEN t1.f=t2.f THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
              (SELECT CASE WHEN t1.g=t2.g THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      AS mtch FROM public.table2 AS t2 ) AS tmp );
```

Comment: Where is your joining column in table 2?

Comment: Actually the data in table2 is only from a:g and there's no joining column

Comment: Then how are you concluding that `After updating table1.status, the outcome will be 5 because the maximum matches are in second row (100, 105, 110, 126, 188)`

Comment: `Table2` is just a fixed data which won’t be updated, only `table1` column `status` will be updated after fetching the maximum matches from `table2/rows`

Comment: When you have no matching column between table1 and table2, How are you concluding that table1.status should have value as 5.

Comment: I think you got confused with the question,,, I have edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below query should work for you -

```
UPDATE public.table1 AS t1 SET status = 
(SELECT MAX(tmp.mtch)
  FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t1.a IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e, t2.f, t2.g) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
               SUM(CASE WHEN t1.b IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e, t2.f, t2.g) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
               SUM(CASE WHEN t1.c IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e, t2.f, t2.g) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
               SUM(CASE WHEN t1.d IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e, t2.f, t2.g) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
               SUM(CASE WHEN t1.e IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e, t2.f, t2.g) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
               SUM(CASE WHEN t1.f IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e, t2.f, t2.g) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
               SUM(CASE WHEN t1.g IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e, t2.f, t2.g) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
               AS mtch
          FROM public.table2 AS t2 ) AS tmp )
 WHERE t1.grade>0;
```

Comment: The query is working perfectly after removing `SUM` function however, taking extremally long hours to update the entire report. Is there any option to reduce execution time of query plz?

Comment: You can try using indices on grade column.

Comment: can you please provide the script to try using indices

Comment: Create an index on column grade on table1.

Comment: I am beginner in PostgreSQL hence, would really appreciate if you could provide the script.

Comment: CREATE INDEX grade_idx ON table1 (grade);